# How do I link my onclick event to an external javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I linked my JavaScript to my HTML file so I'm not sure why the function `setUser` isn't being called when I click this button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat Demo</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="client_style.css"/>
</head>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> 

<body>
    <h1 class = "text"> THE LEMON LAW </h1>
    <div id="error-container" ></div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
        <li><input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your Name!" ></li>
        <li><input id="age" type="text" name="age" value="" placeholder="Enter your Age!" ></li>
        <li><input id="gender" type="text" name="gender" value="" placeholder="Enter your Gender!" ></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setUser()">Start chating!</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/chat.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my function within the javascript file

```
function setUser(){ // set username event listener 
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;

    //send user name to server
    socket.emit('setUser', {name:name , age:age, gender:gender});
};
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: are you sure the function isn't being called? add a `console.log()` statement inside the function and see if it prints the statement to the console or not. Also, please provide more part of the HTML code.

Comment: @RitikSaxena I've added the rest of my HTML code, I also added a console.log() statement and nothing is being printed to the console when I click the button.

Comment: Working for me: http://jsbin.com/vizafuteyi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @MartinGuo Yes, the `console.log()` works for me too.

Comment: I ended up wrapping the entire Javascript file within a <script> tag in my HTML file and that was able to get the function to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't defined `socket` in your client code.

Here try this.

**html** file

//Note that I've used online paths for `socket.io` and `jquery`. You don't need to use them . You can continue with your own `<script>` reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat Demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class = "text"> THE LEMON LAW </h1>
    <div id="error-container" ></div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
        <li><input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your Name!" ></li>
        <li><input id="age" type="text" name="age" value="" placeholder="Enter your Age!" ></li>
        <li><input id="gender" type="text" name="gender" value="" placeholder="Enter your Gender!" ></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setUser()">Start chating!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**new.js** file

// use the right reference for your file name. I've just used new as an example.

```
function setUser(){ // set username event listener 
        name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        socket.emit('setUser', {name:name , age:age, gender:gender}); //send user name to server
        console.log("setUser Called"); //to check if it's calling this function. Just used to show you.
    };
```

The function is called and the socket tries to connect to the host. You'll have to be sure while defining `socket`. I've connected to my `localhost` configured by `Apache server`

The standard way to define socket is this:

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8090');
//io is a global variable and hence no need to define it.
```

Here notice we also define the port number .`8090` is just used as an example